# Data Analysis and sites

Tags: support, site-recommendation, data-analysis

Which site is suitable to include questions on data analysis?

I'd like to post a question about theorical techniques that are applied to analyze the data and feedback that can be given after this analysis and how the subsequent analysis can be influenced by past analyzes.

Comment: Perhaps the Cross Validated SE (Stats SE)? http://stats.stackexchange.com/ Have a look through their faq. I'm not participating there, so I'm not sure. Therefore a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cross Validated - Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) is suitable for questions on data analysis, as @Bart pointed out. Actually, they are quite common.

Just look at:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22data+analysis%22